# Что такое Claims и как они работают ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Какое практическое примение Claims в Asp.Net Identity.  Читаю документацию но так толком не понял для чего они  ?

К примеру у меня есть таблица с пользователями Users(Имя, фамилия, почта и т.д), что будет или должно хранится в Claims?

Comment: читайте тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/21647975/7198805

Comment: 1) [Авторизация в ASP.NET Core MVC](https://habrahabr.ru/post/322566/)       2) [Утверждения (Claims) в ASP.NET Identity](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/identity/level1/1_9.php)